# Model table name gets lower-cased in Laravel 5.4 - seems to only happen for 'account'?

Tags: php, oracle, laravel-5.4

I'm using Laravel 5.4 connecting to Oracle DB.

The table created is named ACCOUNT (uppercase).

I created my model class called Account, and set:

```
protected $table = 'account';
```

When I execute any query using either this model or table account, the table name gets double quoted and QueryException is thrown:

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 647:
Error Code : 942
Error Message : ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
Position : 29
Statement : select * from (select * from "account" where "account"."ID" = :p0) where rownum = 1
Bindings : [123]
(SQL: select * from (select * from "account" where "account"."ID" = 123) where rownum = 1)
```

Apparently, Oracle will not be able to find table "account" because only "ACCOUNT" exist. And if the table name is not double quoted (then it wouldn't be case-sensitive).

So, when I change the table name to account2, the table name gets upper-cased??

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 647:
Error Code : 942
Error Message : ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
Position : 29
Statement : select * from (select * from "ACCOUNT2" where "ACCOUNT2"."ID" = :p0) where rownum = 1
Bindings : [461060]
(SQL: select * from (select * from "ACCOUNT2" where "ACCOUNT2"."ID" = 461060) where rownum = 1)
```

Question is...

1. Are we able to remove the double quoting?
2. If not, how do we prevent the framework from changing the case for table and field names?
3. I've tried configuring oracle drive in app/database.php  
       **'options' => [ PDO::ATTR_CASE => PDO::CASE_UPPER, // enabling this breaks model relationships]** , but this breaks model relationships (e.g., $user->account->id , will throw attempting to access non-object exception as account for user will return null instead. and by not setting the options as above, the relationship is not broken.)

Comment: And what about changing `protected $table = 'account';` to `protected $table = 'ACCOUNT';` ?

Comment: Should have mentioned this too.. Tried that and it does not work either. The word account simply gets lower-cased. I'm fact, I've also tried this - wrap DB::raw("select * from ACCOUNT"), the word account still gets lower cased and double quoted.